# SOAP Address in android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am developing a android mobile application using java. I am trying to use a web service to retrieve information from SQL server that resides on my desktop computer to the mobile application. I have created the web service in visual studio. I get the following error when I run the mobile application.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
```

I know something is wrong with the SOAP address I have specified. I know the SOAP address is the URL that i get when I run the web service in visual studio. So when I run the web service the URL is:

```
 http://localhost:54714/WebSite1/Service.asmx
```

How do I specify the SOAP address? This is some of the code:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/findContact";

private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "findContact";// your webservice web metod name

private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

//What do I have to change in the URL here?

private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:54714/WebSite1/Service.asmx";
```

Comment: is sever  on system in which you are running the emulator?

Comment: I am running it on a mobile device.

Comment: so how can your device detect localhost ? it need a valid Static ip...

Comment: I ment an IP which you can access from your android native browser as well...

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get this IP so that I can run it using a mobile device. If you can give me link that tells how to do this,it will be very helpful

Comment: not so simple ..even I also never did .......http://corz.org/comms/hardware/router/static.ip.address.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http: //loacl host:54714 not works for device should be a valid ip address

if sever is on system in which you are running the emulator then can use

IP address 10.0.2.2 see [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)